# How to use .query without having to specify a particular Id in dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb which has multiple entries with the Firstname Peter, I want to retrieve all the entries which have "Peter" as the first name. How would I do that using .query without having to specify a particular Id. right now I am getting the error: Query condition missed key schema element: Id".

```
   router.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {

        //name3 = "Peter";

       // id = ':id';

        var params = {
            TableName:table,
            //KeyConditionExpression: 'Firstname = :thename AND Id = :id',
            KeyConditionExpression: 'Firstname = :thename',
            //KeyConditionExpression: "Id = :id",

            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':thename': "Peter",
                //':id':id
            }

        }

        let users = docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                handleError(err, res);
            } else {

                console.log(data);          
                res.json({ message: 'success', statusCode: 200, data: data })

            }
         });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can't do that using `query`.

On the other hand you can use `docClient.scan`. ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property)). It is less efficient because it does a full scan, but you don't need to provide an ID